# How to get a return value from async function to a variable in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native app with an authentication process. To get the Authentication, I use Async Storage to store the token and retrieve the token.

I created a method to get the token from the Async storage, but the problem is, I can't use the token in other functions by assigning it to another variable. The function call of the method I created always returns a Promise instead of the token.

App.js

```
const getToken = async () => {
  var value = "";
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken').then(val => {
      value = val;
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error getting token", e)
  }
  console.log("token", value) // here I can see the correct token
  return value;
}

const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => {
    if (Auth.isAuthenticated()) {

      var idToken = getToken().then(t => { return t });
      console.log("token", idToken) // here it is a Promise

      if (idToken) {
        return <Component {...props} />
      }
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: `/signup` }} />
    }
    else {
      // return <Component {...props} />
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: `/signup` }} />
    }
  }} />
)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a Promise, all the code depending on the promise will need to be chain using Promise.then(functionThatDoesMoreThings) or you will need to await Promise... and then do things.

Most people prefer async/await... so in your case it will look like:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={async props => {
    if (Auth.isAuthenticated()) {

      var idToken = await getToken();
      console.log("token", idToken) // it should print the token

      if (idToken) {
        return <Component {...props} />
      }
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: `/signup` }} />
    }
    else {
      // return <Component {...props} />
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: `/signup` }} />
    }
  }} />
```

Comment: is the `async` really for top function instead of the inner one ?
( `... render ={ async props => ...` instead of `async ({ component...`

Comment: @SimonDehaut you are right. I fixed my code.